# follow of curl for java

Tags: java, curl

i want how to follow the link...

for example the link :  http://example.com/hi.php

this will redirect another page to http://example.com/vi.php

then this will redirect another page to http://example.com/ji.html

so i need to get the page link "http://example.com/ji.html"

i think, i cant in java.. so have possible in java curl?

thanks advance

Answer (score 1):

See

Apache Http Client 4.0 using parameter "http.protocol.handle-redirects"